# Automatically get signed request token

Tags: php, curl, oauth

From my understanding of OAuth, the flow is:

1. Get unsigned request token
2. Get signed request token by getting user authorization
3. Get access token

I would like to use php curl to get the signed request token automatically. Once I have the unsigned request token, I'd like a function to go to authorization url, sign in and return the authorized request token.  Basically mimicking basic authorization with username and password.  Is this possible?

I understand it can't be a general solution since the curl postdata will have to be specific to the site.

Thanks

Here's some code and I hope it helps to show you what I'm trying to do.

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $url = 'https://www.scoop.it/oauth/authorize?' . http_build_query(array('oauth_token' => $requestToken['oauth_token'], 'oauth_callback' => $callbackurl));

    $postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);   
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $response = curl_exec($ch)
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Comment: Please be specific what you are asking for. Do you want to want to connect to some service (like Twitter)? Or do you want to learn to write an OAuth client?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to Scoop.it to use their API.  I'm using the pecl OAuth module for an OAuth library.  I have gotten an unsigned request token and I'm at the step where I need to redirect the user to the authorization url.  I'd like to automate the redirect step.

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to:

1. fetch an unauthorized request token
2. redirect the user to  authorization URL with the token and callback URL

You already completed step 1; fetching the access token. Now you must tell the user's browser to redirect to authorization URL.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: '.$AUTHORIZE_URL_WITH_TOKEN);
```

And remember, you have to send out all headers before the first `print()` or `echo()` that ever happens.

Comment: The authorize url takes the user to a login page for the user to authorize the request token.  I need to be able to go to that login page, fill in the username and password fields and hit submit automatically and then get the authorized request token.  Is that possible? Sorry I'm very new to PHP/CURL/OAuth.

Comment: Thats the **whole point** of the authorization page. The user must authorize your app to act on his behalf. But dont worry, access tokens live for a very long time.